# How can one calculate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, fourier-series

I am working through a textbook for my Fourier Series class and I came across the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$. I know from the context of the question that the answer has to be $-\frac{\pi^2}{12}$, but I am not sure how to arrive at this answer. I tried partial fraction decomposition to see if there was any telescoping behavior, but I had an issue with the $(-1)^n$ part.

Comment: Hello, thank you for editing the title, I am just starting with LaTeX for my grade 10 mathematics class, and I did not know about the \infty representation of infinity.

Comment: I think the sum is negative though?

Comment: Asked [so often](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B(-1)%5En%7D%7Bn%5E2%7D%24&p=1)... Let yourself choose the best fit.

Comment: Maybe check this post https://math.stackexchange.com/q/620825/254075

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you know $S:=\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{1}{n^{2}} = \frac{\pi^{2}}{6}$, we get (and I'll replace $(-1)^{n}$ with $(-1)^{n-1}$ which seems that you actually intended to be positive)

$$
\frac{1}{1^2} -\frac{1}{2^{2}} + \frac{1}{3^{2}} - \frac{1}{4^{2}} + \cdots \\
= \frac{1}{1^{2}} + \frac{1}{2^{2}} + \frac{1}{3^{2}} + \frac{1}{4^{2}} + \cdots \\
- 2 \left(\frac{1}{2^{2}} + \frac{1}{4^{2}} + \frac{1}{6^{2}} + \cdots\right) \\
= S - 2\cdot \frac{1}{2^{2}}S = \frac{1}{2}S = \frac{\pi^{2}}{12}
$$

Comment: Thanks so much!